# grails dynamic scaffolding - skip a field to render in view

Tags: grails, scaffolding

Is there any way to make some fields of a domain invisible in dynamic scaffolding view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it myself:

We can use the `display` constraint to achieve this.

source : http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html

```
class {
    String notToDisplay
    ...

    static constraints = {
        ...
        notToDisplay(display:false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the Fields plugin and override the `notToDisplay` field with an empty template so that it doesn't get displayed. This is a bit cleaner, since it doesn't pollute your domain layer with view-specific stuff.

Comment: sounds great! i will certainly try it out.